# Mysql update with subquery join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the update query:

```
UPDATE cash_billings_bills_articles 
    SET cash_billings_bills_articles.cashbillingbillarticle_cost = (SELECT articles_pricehistory.articlepricehistory_cost
                                            FROM articles_pricehistory
                                            LEFT JOIN cash_billings_bills
                                                 ON cash_billings_bills_articles.cashbillingbill_id = cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbill_id
                                            WHERE articles_pricehistory.article_id = cash_billings_bills_articles.article_id AND
                                                 articles_pricehistory.articlepricehistory_date <= cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbill_date
                                            ORDER BY articles_pricehistory.articlepricehistory_date DESC
                                            LIMIT 1
                                           );
```

But i got the error: `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'cash_billings_bills_articles.cashbillingbill_id' in 'on clauseError Code: 1054. Unknown column 'cash_billings_bills_articles.cashbillingbill_id' in 'on clause' 0.000 sec`

**UPDATE** Tables Structures:

[image]

Comment: show your table structures

Comment: @KiranMuralee Please reload the site to view the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join condition seems to be wrong .In your query you try to join tables `articles_pricehistory` and `cash_billings_bills` on condition

```
cash_billings_bills_articles.cashbillingbill_id = cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbill_id
```

where `cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbill_id` column should be compared with some column of `articles_pricehistory` table **not  `cash_billings_bills_articles` table**.

Your query should be more like

```
UPDATE cash_billings_bills_articles 
SET 
    cash_billings_bills_articles.cashbillingbillarticle_cost = (SELECT 
            articles_pricehistory.articlepricehistory_cost
        FROM
            articles_pricehistory
                LEFT JOIN
            cash_billings_bills_articles ON cash_billings_bills_articles.article_id = articles_pricehistory.article_id
                LEFT JOIN
            cash_billings_bills ON cash_billings_bills_articles.cashbillingbill_id = cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbill_id
        WHERE
            articles_pricehistory.articlepricehistory_date <= cash_billings_bills.cashbillingbill_date
        ORDER BY articles_pricehistory.articlepricehistory_date DESC
        LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: @JonathanEdgardo glad to know :)